# .Net Core Blazor Server-side. Execute exe and bat files on deployed server

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, blazor

I am developing and distributing it with Blazor server-side and I'm trying to run exe,bat files on the deployed server.
When run with the following code, it runs very well in local, but when deployed to the server, it does not run.
The deployed server environment is being distributed with IIS.

Please let me know if you have any other settings for running files on the server.
Or if the code is wrong. I hope for help.

```
=============== Function Definition ===============
public void ExecuteCommand(string command)
{
    int exitCode;
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
    Process process = new Process();
    processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C " + command);
    processInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "test");
    processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processInfo.Verb = "runas";

    processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    process = Process.Start(processInfo);
    process.WaitForExit();

    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    exitCode = process.ExitCode;
    Console.WriteLine("output>>" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(output) ? "(none)" : output));
    Console.WriteLine("error>>" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(error) ? "(none)" : error));
    Console.WriteLine("ExitCode: " + exitCode.ToString(), "ExecuteCommand");
    process.Close();
}

=============== Execute Function ===============

ExecuteCommand(string.Format("batchTest.bat {0}", userDirPath));
```

Comment: When your running it local your running it under your credentials. When you deploy you are running it under the Apppool's permissions..

Comment: @BrianParker Thank you for your reply! but I am facing another problem...
I ran the code as above, but the cmd window did not appear on the screen or on the taskbar.
However, I noticed that cmd task was displayed in the task manager. Is this also a permission issue?

Comment: I noticed that you set the processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
It shouldnt create the window. Set it to false to create the window (at least for testing)